# Replace NaN with null kusto

Tags: null, nan, azure-data-explorer

I have a problem with a kusto query and I need your help:

I developed a query that results in a table with several columns. The problem is that sometimes some of these columns come with the NaN result, this causes an error when data is being transferred to the database via the azure pipeline.
Is there a kusto expression or command that allows me to check my results table and replace NaN with null?[Query result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We5pR.jpg)
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use isnan() function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/isnanfunction

```
datatable(a:double)
[
    1.1,
    double(NaN)
]
| extend b = iif(isnan(a), double(null), a)
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer - To emphasize using `double(null)` is required to make it work